# Who was James Elia?

Tags: essays, charles-lamb

In the essay “Dream Children: A Reverie” by Charles Lamb, the last few lines by the children read

> I found myself quietly seated in my bachelor arm-chair where I had fallen asleep, with the faithful Bridget unchanged by my side - but John L (or James Elia) was gone for ever.

Who was James Elia? Bartrum was the father of the children of Alice W—-n, and Charles was a rejected lover of Alice W—-n.

Answer (score 1):

Lamb wrote some personal essays in the persona of 'Phil-Elia', the children in this particular essay are those he might have had if his suit with Alice W----n had succeeded.

The Dream Children are named Alice and John, memorialising the Alice who married Bartram and Lamb's(Elia's) brother John.

John L (or James Elia) is Charles Lamb's older brother, as featured in the reverie of Lamb's essayist alter-ego.